# "zu Mittag(Abend) essen"-breaking down into sentence members

Tags: meaning

I have a question concerning the following phrases: "zu Abend essen"; "zu Mittag essen". The question is what type of sentence member do "zu Abend" and "zu Mittag" belong to? Are they basically adverbials of time or manner? It is just I'm having hard time trying to position them correctly in sentences. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My interpretation is that these are fixed phrases which function as a verb. I think you're thinking of the "time–manner–place" (TMP) rule for word order in German. If so then you should know that this is more of a guideline than a rule. German word order is flexible and while the TMP rule is kind of the default order in most situations, the order can change according to emphasis and other factors. Not only that, in certain situations, such as this, what counts as time, what counts and manner, and what counts as place can be hard to determine, so the rule can be difficult to apply in some cases. I think for the purposes of the TMP rule, you can regarded the "zu Abend/Mittag" sub-phrase as a place, so "Ich esse gerade zu Mittag" would be more natural than "Ich esse zu Mittag gerade.